# Using Checkbox Data to make schedules for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an issue with my code for some reason I cannot figure out. I have a website with checkboxes (Monday-Friday) and the user is able to choose which days they are available for the week. I am able to get and store the data from the checkboxes with no issue, but my problem is the scheduling code. For example, say the user chooses Monday and Tuesday for the days they are available, for some reason my scheduling code does not recognize that.

I was thinking perhaps to do something like this but can't seem to implement it right

user chooses Mon and Tues
use CurrentTime.DayOfWeek to compare when user is available
Any tips would be super useful! :)

on the server side:

```
public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        var model = new DaysViewModel();
        model.Days.AddRange( new List<CDay> {
                new CDay("Monday"),
                new CDay("Tuesday"),
         

   new CDay("Wednesday"),
            new CDay("Thursday"),
            new CDay("Friday")
        });
    return View(model);
}
```

the model:

```
public class DaysViewModel  
{
    public List<CDay> Days { get; set; } = new List<CDay>();
}

public class CDay
{
    public CDay()
    {
        Name = string.Empty;
        Selected = false;
    }

    public CDay(string name) 
    {
        Name = name;
        Selected = false; 
    }      

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

asp.net

```
@model Models.DaysViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home"))
{   
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
    for(int i=0; i < Model.Days.Count; i++)  
    {
        <div class="form-group row">
        @Html.CheckBox("Days[" + i + "].Selected", Model.Days[i].Selected)   
        @Html.Hidden("Days[" + i + "].Name", Model.Days[i].Name)
        <span>@Model.Days[i].Name </span>   
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

my scheduling code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < days.Count; i++)
{
   if (days[i].Selected.Equals(true))
    {
        // schedule code here
        // for some reason does not detect which days user chooses 
    }
}
```

Comment: did u mean u want the checkbox to check for those day the user had chosen before?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean! The code I have though should check for that so thats why Im confused to why it doesnt work, I have debugged it too

Answer (score 0):

The model of booking to be saved

```
 public class StaffBooking
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        public DateTime BookDate { get; set; }
    }
```

And then I create a ViewModel for the booking purpose

```
public class StaffBookingVM
    {
        public DateTime FromDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime ToDate { get; set; }
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        public List<ScheduleDate> ScheduleDates;
        private readonly WorkshopProContext db;

        public StaffBookingVM(WorkshopProContext _db)
        {
            db = _db;
            ScheduleDates = new List<ScheduleDate>();
        }


        public void GetSchedule()
        {

            do
            {
                ScheduleDate newItem = new ScheduleDate
                {
                    StaffId = StaffId,
                    SelDate = FromDate,
                    Booked = db.StaffBooking.Where(a => a.StaffId == StaffId && a.BookDate == FromDate).Any()
                };

                ScheduleDates.Add(newItem);

                FromDate = FromDate.AddDays(1);

            } while (FromDate < ToDate);
        }

    }

    public class ScheduleDate
    {
        public int StaffId { get; set; }
        public DateTime SelDate { get; set; }
        public bool Booked { get; set; }
    }
```

The Controller

```
public class ScheduleController : Controller
    {
        private readonly StaffBookingVM VM;

        public ScheduleController(StaffBookingVM _VM)
        {
            VM = _VM;
        }

           
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GenerateSchedule()
        {
            VM.FromDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-5);
            VM.ToDate = DateTime.Today;
            VM.StaffId = 1;
            VM.GetSchedule();
            return View(VM);

        }
    }
```

And the View

```
@model WorkshopPro.ViewModels.StaffBookingVM


<table class="table">
@foreach (var item in Model.ScheduleDates)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @if (@item.Booked == true)
                {
                    <input type="submit" name="Selected" value="@item.SelDate" checked="checked">
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="submit" name="Selected" value="@item.SelDate">
                }
            
        </td>
        <td>@item.SelDate</td>

    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I hope you get the idea. build a view model and query whether record exist. There u can determine whether the checkbox is checked.